# Is there a way to convert list of string formatted dictionary to a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I am practicing how to use beautifulsoup and currently in a pickle as I can't convert the results to a dataframe. Hope to get your help.

In this example, the page I want to scrape can be obtained using the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get("https://store.moncler.com/en-ca/women/autumn-winter/view-all-outerwear?tp=72010&ds_rl=1243188&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIpfDj9bjP5wIVlJOzCh0-9ghJEAAYASAAEgLuSfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds", verify = False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

I have managed to isolate to the product section using the following code

```
test_class = []

for section_tag in soup.find_all('section', class_='search__products__shelf search__products__shelf--moncler'):
    for test in section_tag.find_all('article'):
        test_class.append(test.get('data-ytos-track-product-data'))
```

The result of this is a list of **string-formatted** dictionary which looks like the following:

> ['{"product_position":0,"product_title":"TREPORT","product_brand":"MONCLER","product_category":"3074457345616676837/3074457345616676843","product_micro_category":"Outerwear","product_micro_category_id":"3074457345616676843","product_macro_category":"OUTERWEAR","product_macro_category_id":"3074457345616676837","product_color_id":"Dark
>   blue","product_color":"Dark
>   blue","product_price":0.0,"product_discountedPrice":2530.0,"product_price_tf":"0","product_discountedPrice_tf":"2126.05","product_id":"1890828705323513","product_variant_id":"1890828705323514","list":"searchresult","product_quantity":1,"product_coupon":"","product_cod8":null,"product_cod10":null,"product_legacy_macro_id":"1012","product_legacy_micro_id":"1446","product_is_in_stock":true,"is_rsi_product":false,"rsi_product_tracking_url":""}',
>   '{"product_position":1,"product_title":"RIMAC","product_brand":"MONCLER","product_category":"3074457345616676837/3074457345616676854","product_micro_category":"Bomber
>   Jacket","product_micro_category_id":"3074457345616676854","product_macro_category":"OUTERWEAR","product_macro_category_id":"3074457345616676837","product_color_id":"Dark
>   blue","product_color":"Dark
>   blue","product_price":0.0,"product_discountedPrice":2340.0,"product_price_tf":"0","product_discountedPrice_tf":"1966.39","product_id":"5549023491788128","product_variant_id":"5549023491788129","list":"searchresult","product_quantity":1,"product_coupon":"","product_cod8":null,"product_cod10":null,"product_legacy_macro_id":"1012","product_legacy_micro_id":"4715","product_is_in_stock":true,"is_rsi_product":false,"rsi_product_tracking_url":""}',

My question is how to convert the result to a pandas dataframe from a list of **string formatted** dictionary like that?

I have tried to use the code below to start with

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(test_class[1])
```

but to no avail (it gives me below error code).

> ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at
>   0x000001985A976748>

The end result should store each key of the dictionary into columns in a Dataframe (ie. 'product_position','product_title','product_brand',etc)

Any help / guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the question really is about how to parse a string, not how to do something with pandas.

The list you have seem to contain simply valid json strings. You can convert them to python dict's using `json.loads()` from the standard lib. Of course if some strings are malformed that's another story, you'll have to google how to parse malformed jsons.

After getting a list of python dicts turning them into a DataFrame is trivial.

Comment: omg thanks for the hint! I've successfully managed to turn the json object into DataFrame using simple loop and list comprehension. If there's a built in pandas function or something better, im all ears..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `json.loads` and then instantiate `pandas.DataFrame` with the obtained list of  dictionaries:

```
d = [json.loads(e) for e in data]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```